# How can I dynamically set connection string in MVC 5 based on incoming request?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC 5 application that is currently single tenant only, but that is becoming unmanageable as our client-base grows.

I would like to turn this application into a multi-tenant app, accessing a distinct database for each client.

The client's are easily distinguishable by their domain, which I can access through Request.Url.Host or other methods, but once I have this property, I am having trouble setting it in the Business logic project within the context of that request only.

The Business logic project is referenced by the main Web project, but that project is blink to the Request object, so I do not know how to get that session information dynamically each time the baseDataAccess (which contains the connection strings) object is instantiated.

I've spent many many hours on this, and have tried using Ninject to resolve the dependency with no success. I just can't seem to figure out how to get the dynamic Request object or any of its properties to assign transiently to the baseDataAccess object.

The last thing I tried was using and IActionFilter using the OnActionExecuting method, but I am still unable to figure out how to set the value of the URL for each request dynamically in a project that has no context for the current request.

This is the class I want to set dynamically. the _connectionString is the dynamic property. I have methods to build the connection string based on the url, so if I can set the _domain property dynamically and transiently I'll be able to get the connection string.

```
public class baseDataAccess : IDataAccess
{
    private static IClientConnection _clientConnection;
    private static string _connectionString;
    public static string _domain;
```

...

This is the last attempt I made, adding the OnActionExecuting method to each controller. How can I set these properties dynamically and transiently?

```
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        IClientConnection client = new ClientConnectionFactory(Request.Url.Host);
        IDataAccess dataAccess = new baseDataAccess(client);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm have the same need for my application. I have to set the connection String with the user information depending on the user login. I added a reference on `System.Web` to get the `Session` object in my business layer.

The main idea is, to store the current user in the `Session` and let the business logic access this `Session` with `HttpContext.Current.Session` now my database classes can read the connection string dynamically on every single access to the database.

And as the user session is available in any library that has the `System.Web` reference, it can be used application wide. So there is no problem setting the connection string on the `Session_Start` event depending on the request from the user.

Comment: I think you solved this for me. Something so simple I spent so many hours on... I had to explicitly add the System.Web assembly to the project instead of using the inferred System.Web namespace already included.